# varnish 4.0.1, Unknown command: "vcl", but command is needed on header?

Tags: debian, varnish

I am on Debian Jessie, Varnish 4.0.1

From the varnish 4 Wiki : `"Starting with Varnish 4.0, each VCL file must start by declaring its version with a special "vcl 4.0;" marker at the top of the file."`

I have grabbed this config made [for Wordpress here](https://github.com/nicolargo/varnish-nginx-wordpress/blob/master/varnish/varnish4-wordpress), and it actually works.

But it seems that as some parts of the config are failing, some functions are not working and I can't log any user on my installation.

The code  "`vcl 4.0;`" is failing when I do a test :

```
*    top   0.0 TEST /etc/varnish/default.vcl starting
---- top   0.0 Unknown command: "vcl"
*    top   0.0 RESETTING after /etc/varnish/default.vcl
*    top   0.0 TEST /etc/varnish/default.vcl FAILED
```

If the initial marker fails, and I am on Varnish 4.0.1, is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Are you sure that you are in 4.0.1? Please run varnishd -V, perhaps you have multiple installations and you are running an older one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait a minute, you are testing your VCL with varnishtest, that's not the correct tool to use.

varnishtest is a program to test varnish cache, it reads script files to test the server (see man varnishtest)

If you want to load your vcl in a running varnish use varnishadm:

```
vcl.load vcl1 /etc/varnish/default.vcl
200
VCL compiled.
vcl.list
200
active          0 boot
available       0 vcl1
vcl.use vcl1
200        
VCL 'vcl1' now active
```

Or pass it with the -f parameter of varnishd when starting it.

Comment: You were right. I am sure I read before on the docs I was following that varnishtest was the tool to test your .vcl's